# Storing billions of unsigned ints for lookup

Tags: data-structures

I need to store billions of unsigned 64 bit ints in a data structure that supports lookup of these ints. Currently the solution is to use a bloomfilter which generally works, and gives me a probability that a given int is in the stored set. This is working fine for now, however given the error rate setup in the bloomfilter and the sheer amount of distinct ints, it currently takes up several GB of memory (about 5GB).

Is there a data structure that could potentially allow me to do non-probabilistic lookups and that would take up less or just as much space? I looked at Tries and X-fast-trie's both of which would work but take too much memory.

Comment: You can possibly save some space, although there are tradeoffs. See https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf. If your numbers are essentially random, then you're unlikely to get space efficient non-probabilistic lookup. You *might* be able to do it if you can take advantage of patterns in the numbers.